# How to concatenate strings in a for-loop?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, string-concatenation

I'm using a loop in C and trying to determine how `fprintf` works.

```
fprintf(out, "%02X", (int)(ch & 0x00FF);
```

This statement prints out a single hex value char for every iteration of the loop.

Can I store this in a variable or char array?

How can I concatenate this into one large string, and then write it to the file?

Do I have to check the total size of the iterations, and set the char array to the correct size of the loop at the beginning, and then append to this?

Comment: What do you expect it to print ?

Comment: I was hoping to store each hex value for each iteration in a long string, which I can print out at once (at the end of the loop)

Comment: At the moment it prints one hex value for each iteration - which is expected, but I want to change it to one output at the end.

Comment: @Ke what is the problem? Is it, how to store the values? Or how to make them hex characters?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use `sprintf()` instead: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/ "Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf, but instead of being printed, the content is stored as a C string in the buffer pointed by str."

Comment: ahh nice, im new to this buffer pointed by str but will investigate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help.

The program expects a number of decimal inputs (max 50). It prints the corresponding hex value and append the char to a string (zero terminated char array). Finally, it prints the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int N = 50;
    int i = 0;
    char text[N+1];  // Make an array to hold the string
    text[0] = '\0';  // Zero terminate it
    int ch;

    while(i < N)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &ch) != 1)  // Read decimal from stdin
        {
            break;                  // Break out if no decimal was returned
        }
        printf("%02X ", (ch & 0x00FF));

        text[i] = (ch & 0x00FF);  // Add the new char
        text[i+1] = '\0';         // Add a new string termination
        ++i;

    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

65 66 67 68

**Output:**

41 42 43 44

ABCD

Or this alternative which read a string char-by-char until it sees a newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int N = 50;
    int i = 0;
    char text[N+1];
    text[0] = '\0';
    char ch;

    while(i <= N)
    {
        if (scanf("%c", &ch) != 1 || ch == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%02X ", ch);
        text[i] = ch;
        text[i+1] = '\0';
        ++i;
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

coding is fun

**Output:**

63 6F 64 69 6E 67 20 69 73 20 66 75 6E

coding is fun

Comment: I'm wondering how does the 1st one work? I notice that there is an "input" how do I get this input into the main function for processing? Also, does the char array size need to be double the size, due to the \0 being added after every character?

Comment: @Ke. `scanf("%d", &ch)` reads an integer from stdin. If the return value is 1 (i.e. success) the value read, is stored in `ch`. The array doesn't need to be double size. There is only 1 termination. Therefore array size is `N+1` so that it can hold N characters and 1 termination.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very sure what you want to do but you can check this code I did for you and maybe extend it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{


  char buff[2056];
  char out[255];
  char ch ='a';

  sprintf(out, "%02X", (int)(ch & 0x00FF) ); 

  strcpy(buff,out);
  printf("%s",buff);



  return 0;
}
```